# rescue inside do loops and conditionals ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following body of code that is in theory supposed to rescue the error inside of the nested conditional block. However; it is not working. I tried moving the rescue and begin statements inside of both blocks but neither is working.

```
begin
  @acceptrecent = Accept.where("buyer_id = ? OR localbid = ?", current_user, current_user).order(created_at: :desc).limit(5)
  @offersrecent = Offer.where(buyer_id:current_user, offerstat: true).order(updated_at: :desc).limit(20)
  @buyer = Buyer.find(current_user)
  @acceptrecent.each do |item|
    unless item.processed.present?
      item.cart.nil? ? tracker = TrackDefault.new : tracker = USPS::Request::TrackingFieldLookup.new(item.cart.track_number,1).send!
      item.status = tracker.status
      item.save
    end
  end
rescue USPS::Error => err
  tracker = TrackDefault.new
end
```

Comment: I should clarify. The code is able to survive, but item.status is not being set to the rescued value. Instead it is receiving nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when an exception is raised, the execution jumps into rescue section, so all the necessary code is skipped. Try to put `begin...rescue...end` block inside the loop:

```
@acceptrecent = Accept.where("buyer_id = ? OR localbid = ?", current_user, current_user).order(created_at: :desc).limit(5)
@offersrecent = Offer.where(buyer_id:current_user, offerstat: true).order(updated_at: :desc).limit(20)
@buyer = Buyer.find(current_user)
@acceptrecent.each do |item|
  unless item.processed.present?
    tracker =
      begin
        item.cart ? USPS::Request::TrackingFieldLookup.new(item.cart.track_number,1).send! : TrackDefault.new
      rescue USPS::Error => _
        TrackDefault.new
      end

    item.status = tracker.status
    item.save
  end
end
```